# Why does this Javascript break required validation?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET web forms application where one page is used to submit orders.  What was happening is some users when clicking on Submit would not wait for the page to be processed (which sometimes would take a few seconds) and press the Submit button again. This caused creation of duplicate order.

To prevent the above problem I added the following code to the Page_load of the page:

```
Submit.Attributes.Add("onclick", " this.disabled = true; " +   ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(Submit, null) + ";");
```

What happens now is that all validations are broken on the page.  That is, when user clicks on Submit, while some required field are left empty, the text of the asp:requiredfieldvalidator briefly appears but the page gets submitted.

How can I change the above code so that the required validation would still work?

Comment: can't you move the code to disable the button inside the validate function? Then, if only validated the button is disabled..

Comment: @plbsam  Sorry I don't understand what you are suggesting.  The required field validation is done by way of asp:requiredfieldvalidator. So which "validate function" do you mean?

Comment: Sorry. I have no experience with asp validations. I just suggested to change the validator code so that button is disabled if validation passes... May be it's not possible with asp..

Answer (score 0):

The validation and postback code is added by asp.net automatically, you don't need to add it yourself if you set your own `onclick`.

So I think by setting the attribute in this way you are adding a second postback call before the validation call. You should just need to add the code to disable the button, either in the code-behind:

```
Submit.Attributes.Add("onclick", " this.disabled = true; ");
```

or the page itself

```
<asp:Button OnClientClick="this.disabled = true;" />
```

Comment: Rhumbori, Thank you very much! This seemed to resolve the issue, first. But then I tested it and what happens is the page is not submitted (when user clicks on  Submit with fields left empty) but the Submit button is disabled. So there is no way to submit again.

Comment: What if the validation fails? then the button shouldn't be disabled. Will this survive that?

Comment: @plbsam  When validation fails the button shouldn't be disabled; you are correct. But it becomes disabled (using the code I posted above). What I need to figure is how to change the Submit.Attribute... code such that it only fires when Page.IsValid returns True.  But I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

Add one more button in html div element and make that div visibility hidden. When user click on the your button. Just fire submit event of that button inside div. and make your button disable. It will work try out

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to this problem is to place it in an Ajax Update-panel, and display a progress-indicator (spinner) after 0 ms delay. This solution doesn't need any Javascript.